# check_mk: global name 'entry' is not defined

Tags: monitoring, nagios, check-mk

I'm having a ton of trouble with a nagios installation I've been working on powered by check_mk and OMD. When using the web gui to manage check_mk, the notifications page displays the following Python error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/omd/sites/keck/share/check_mk/web/htdocs/wato.py", line 304, in page_handler
modefunc("content")
File "/omd/sites/keck/share/check_mk/web/htdocs/wato.py", line 9000,  in mode_notifications
statename = _(entry.get("HOSTSTATE")[:4])
NameError: global name 'entry' is not defined
```

For the life of me, I can't figure this error out. I even wiped my installation and tried setting it up from scratch and got the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a Python error, not PHP.

Comment: Good point, I updated to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

try removing the file "/omd/SITE/var/check_mk/notify/backlog.mk" and create an empty one. Then restart the core. This fixed the issue for me.